# How to calculate 21 factorial in Rust?

Tags: rust, factorial

I need to calculate 21 factorial in my project.

```
fn factorial(num: u64) -> u64 {
    match num {
        0 => 1,
        1 => 1,
        _ => factorial(num - 1) * num,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = factorial(21);
    println!("The value of 21 factorial is {} ", x);
}
```

When running this code, I get an error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to multiply with overflow', src\main.rs:5:18
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `u64` can’t hold 21! (it’s between 2^65 and 2^66), but a `u128` can.

Answer (score 10):

A possible implementation could be

```rust
pub fn factorial(num: u128) -> u128 {
    (1..=num).product()
}


#[test]
fn factorial_of_21() {
   assert_eq!(51090942171709440000,factorial(21));
}

#[test]
fn factorial_of_0() {
   assert_eq!(1,factorial(0));
}
```

Comment: On time: we can calculate with u128 the 34!  == 295232799039604140847618609643520000000. ;-)

Comment: Why is the input num `u128`? and not `u8`?

Comment: Because the trait Product<u8> is not implemented for u128.

Comment: You can also write this `(1..num+1)` like this `(1..=num)` @FabioPetrillo

Answer (score 7):

> I need to calculate 21 factorial in my project.

21! doesn't fit in a 64 bit int. You need some [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) (or bigint) library or to implement yours, or use 128 bits ints or some floating point.

According to [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software), you could consider using [ramp](https://github.com/Aatch/ramp).

Answer (score 2):

I think the implementation should look like this

```
pub fn factorial(num: u128) -> u128 {
    (1..=num).product()
}
```

Comment: Ah, so not using `.product()` was the problem?

Comment: no the initial problem was about type used by factorial which was u64. I would just share the shortest and efficient way to create this function.