# How to calculate 100000! or more in Rust?

Tags: rust

A function for calculating factorial is as follows. 
But it is clear that usize is not big enough?

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", factorial(100000));
}
fn factorial(n: usize) -> usize {
    (1..n+1).fold(1, |a, b| a * b)
}
```

error message: thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to multiply with overflow'

Later I planned to use recursion to calculate factorial, but the result was `inf`

```
fn factorial(num: f64) -> f64 {
    match num {
        0.0 => 1.0,
        1.0 => 1.0,
        _ => factorial(num - 1.0) * num,
    }
}
```

Comment: The result is a number with 456574 digits.

Comment: Btw, bad idea to use recursion here. For such big numbers you are gonna crash the recursion limit for sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate 21 factorial in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206653/how-to-calculate-21-factorial-in-rust)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Actually, the answer to the question you mentioned does not clearly indicate the use of BigUint

Comment: @StevenZ It's the same question, though, so we could merge them. Makes maintenance easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`BigUint`](https://rust-num.github.io/num/num/struct.BigUint.html) for example:

```
use num::{BigUint, One};

fn factorial(n: usize) -> BigUint {
    (1..=n).fold(BigUint::one(), |a, b| a * b)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9e28ef5b2f0abaa1b8cf731432eff773)

Comment: The compiler said: error[E0432]: unresolved import \`num\`. Is num a new crate?

Comment: @StevenZ, it is a crate indeed: https://rust-num.github.io/num/num/index.html

Comment: It worked, but it felt so slow, not as fast as python?

Comment: uhm, not sure about performance, but I would bet for rust to be faster. Did you compile it in `release` mode?

Comment: @StevenZ For what it's worth, I'd expect Python's factorial algorithm to win hands down against a naive implementation in Rust. It's [written in C an a bit more sophisticated](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5be8241392453751beea21d2e32096c15a8d47db/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1845).

Comment: @SvenMarnach, yep in that case is true, but I think he implemented the same naive algorithm himself.